# Is this a custom beamer template or a stock one?

Tags: beamer, templates, beamer-metropolis

I came across [these slides](http://metalearning-symposium.ml/files/garnett.pdf) on the Internet and the aesthetics of the slides look amazing in my opinion. The slides are clearly made in `beamer` (based on slide 3 and onward), but I can't figure out if this is a custom template that one of the authors created, or if this template is a downloadable theme. Does anyone recognize it (click to enlarge)?

[image]

If it is custom, I would also be interested in seeing if anyone is able to replicate the first three slides.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Welcome! Look at a gallery, like this: https://it.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/presentation, and search for your template.

Comment: First and second slides looks like from `metropolis` but third and fourth not.

Comment: Write an email to the authors and ask them about the theme. You can find the email address of the first author https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~luizgustavo/

Comment: I tried that a week ago and did not receive any response. I emailed all of the authors as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a similar result by adding a footline to moloch theme and tweaking a few colours:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\title{title}
\author{author names}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=orange,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=orange}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=gray!50!white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=gray!70!white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=gray!90!white}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\moloch@enablesectionpage}{
  \AtBeginSection{
    {
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
    \ifbeamer@inframe
      \sectionpage
    \else
      \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
    \fi
  }}
}
\moloch@enablesectionpage

\setlength{\moloch@titleseparator@linewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\moloch@progressonsectionpage@linewidth}{1pt}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\section{section name}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple way to change the fonts? And the size of the fonts on certain pages but not all pages?

Comment: @JohnSmith You mean the font of elements like the title or of the body of the frame?

Comment: Yes I do believe so. Like where it says section name and title.

Comment: @JohnSmith `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge}`, similar for `section title`

Comment: How do you change the font type in your example?

Comment: @JohnSmith By using whatever package that provides the font you'd like (sorry, there is no general solution, this really depends in which way your font is available)

Comment: Ok, I did not know that, thanks.